# Saving data on local computer

Tags: javascript, saving-data

I'm creating a form and would like to save the data.
At the moment the form will be answered on one computer (not online) and the user will also have to print it.
I was wondering if there's a simple way to save every print while "print btn" is being pressed, plus saving the answers of each form on this local computer with out using a server.

The reason I'm trying to make it this way it's because I never learned Javascript and I'm trying to make it simple as possible.

Thank's!

Comment: You're looking for [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 1):

You can save the information for example in the storage of html5 (assuming you're speaking about a web).

The problem is what is a "print"? If It's an image on a canvas and you can retrieve the base64 from that, you could store it also in Html5 storage.

Check this post about Html5 storage functions: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Great! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using IndexDB, and to make the access universal use PouchDB to handled your data access layer.

PouchDB will detect if IndexDB is supported and use that, if it it will default to WebSQL.

I have used this approach to create a local data store on the users PC. I used this in mobile app development too. It is created in the context of end user's  browser, and the data is retained there the next time they visit your site.

This PouchDB link has a download sample ZIP file that shows you how it works.

https://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html

There used to be a simple TO-DO list demo online, but it seems that it is down. http://todomvc.com/

Comment: I will check that out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is mutiple ways to do this, but the data will be saved "inside" the browser:

- [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)
- [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
- Indexed DB

Regarding your needs, i would advise to rather use local Storage